# Cannot restore MBP 16 - macOS Verify failed

Tags: macos, catalina, recovery

When I try to reinstall macOS from Recovery, the install happens and stops at the end saying "failed to verify macOS"

I have tried:

- Reset NVRAM/PRAM
- Reset SMC
- Tried to change Security setting (no administrator exists anymore)
- Cannot install from external drive due to the security settings
- Currently i do not have access to my time machine backup

Background:

I got a 16inch MacBook Pro and it stopped working during an update. Also there were some weird issues happening on the software as Finder was hanging , and taking lots of time. Since this was migrated OS from multiple computers in the past, i thought this was a good time for a clean install. And stuck with nowhere to go.

Any help would be much appreciated